# multiple string replace

Tags: php

I need to replace multiple text with it's associated text

Example: I have string like: `"apple is a great fruit"`

Now I need to replace `"apple"` to `"stackoverflow"`, and `"fruit"` to `"website"`

I know I can use `str_replace`, but is there any other way? **`str_replace` would be slow in my case**, because I need to replace atleast 5 to 6 words

Help appreciated.

Comment: Replacing 5 or 6 words isn't really slow using str_replace() unless you're doing it in a 100MB file... certainly it's going to be the fastest option within PHP itself

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<?php

$a = array('cheese','milk');
$b = array('old cow','udder');
$str = 'I like cheese and milk';
echo str_replace($a,$b,$str); // echos "I like old cow and udder"
```

Alternatively, if you don't like to look of that (worried of miss matching array values) then you could do:

```
$start = $replace = $array();
$str = "I like old cow and udder"

$start[] = 'cheese';
$replace[] = 'old cow';

$start[] = 'milk';
$replace[] = 'udder';
echo str_replace($start,$replace,$str); // echos "I like old cow and udder"
```

edit: I see dnl has edited the question and put emphasis on the fact that str_replace would be too slow. In my interpretation of the question it is because the user was not aware that they would use arrays in str_replace.

Comment: @diEcho - he says he doesn't want to use the fastest and most appropriate PHP function because it __would be slow in his case__ - why his case should be slow, I don't know, and he hasn't really explained why (replacing 5 or 6 words isn't an explanation, unless he's trying to issue 5 or 6 individual str_replace() statements rather than 1 with arrays)

Comment: As I understand it should be `array()` (without $) in `$start = $replace = $array();` - that's following the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php (otherwise I get an error)

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose `str_replace` seams to be already the fastest solution.

`str_replace` is faster than `strstr`

Source: http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=175031.0

Answer (score 1):

if u know all the word sequence and also replaced word then use below technique

```
$trans = array( "apple" => "stackoverflow", "fruit" => "website");
echo strtr("apple is a great fruit", $trans); // stackoverflow is a great website
```

[Reference](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Comment: strtr is slower than str_replace when using longer strings (source: http://www.cznp.com/blog/3/strtr-vs-str_replace-a-battle-for-speed-and-didignity).